# Apex properties in helper class

Tags: apex, controller, class

I have an apex helper class named `"PricingConversion"` called from my apex controller `"DeaRowEdit"`.

```
PricingConversionHelper.CalculationSecondPricingTon(dealrow);
```

I would like to move the properties related to this calculation in the Helper class, keeping them available for the page.

```
public Decimal RefProductRefPriceShortTon {get; set;}
```

moved in the class "PricingConversionHelper"

Is there a way to call or make them available in `"DealRowEditcontroller"` and the VF page from the helper class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try this

In the controller

```
PricingConversionHelper pch = new PricingConversionHelper();
pch.calculationSecondPricing(dealrow);  // assumes this is an instance method
```

In the VF page

```
apex:outputText value="{!pch.RefProductRefPriceShortTon}"/>  // assumes an instance variable
```

The VF page references the instance of the class, and, once the method has calculated the values, they are available through the getter (or could be set as well)